# Nestjs: start a task schedular from specific time

Tags: node.js, cron, nestjs, cron-task

I'm creating a reminder module that has a `name, start_date, and occur(weekly, monthly, yearly)` fields so when I add a reminder
I just want to create a dynamic cron job to be running from the occurring field

ex:

```
const job = new CronJob(CronExpression.EVERY_WEEK, () => true);
this.schedulerRegistry.addCronJob('new job', job);
job.start()
```

the above one runs every_week from now, but I want to start and run this job at a specific date that is from the start_date field

is there a way to do that?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Date to Cron function.

```
function everyWeekAt(date: Date) {
  return `${date.getSeconds()} ${date.getMinutes()} ${date.getHours()} * * ${date.getDay()}`
}

const job = new CronJob(everyWeekAt(start_date), () => true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your heads up! your example will run like if my start_date is `29/07/2022` then this will start running on  this job from this week when the day is `6`
but in my case, I actually want to run this job only from `29/07/2022`  not from this week itself.

Comment: If you only want to run this job once on that day, you can [add timeout job](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling#dynamic-timeouts). But I don't recommend it. It is recommended to use a delayed queue to achieve better.

If you want to run this job only on this day of the year. You can refer to the above code to write a function `everyYearAt()`.

Hope these help you.